# JavaFX use setId() method for style sheet in different class without creating extra scene

Tags: java, css, javafx

As you can see in my code my makeDigit() and makeSmallDigit() methods are way too long and i want them to be in a separate file, a new class. But how am i to use the setId() method in a different class? Just a led function demonstrated here with way too many leds *(i know there is a separate class provided for that but i am not using it)*

**my main class:**

```
public class Digital_Analog_Clock_Beta_1 extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        double outerBoxWidth = 500, outerBoxHeight = outerBoxWidth / 3;
        Rectangle outerBox = new Rectangle(0, 0, outerBoxWidth, outerBoxHeight);
        outerBox.setId("outer-box");

        Rectangle part1 = new Rectangle(0, 0, outerBoxWidth * .35, outerBoxHeight);
        part1.setId("partition");
        Rectangle part2 = new Rectangle(outerBoxWidth * .35, 0, outerBoxWidth * .05, outerBoxHeight);
        part2.setId("partition-alternate");
        Rectangle part3 = new Rectangle(outerBoxWidth * .4, 0, outerBoxWidth * .35, outerBoxHeight);
        part3.setId("partition");
        Rectangle part4 = new Rectangle(outerBoxWidth * .75, 0, outerBoxWidth * .25, outerBoxHeight);
        part4.setId("partition");

        double bigNumWidth = outerBoxWidth * .35;
        double colonWidth = outerBoxWidth * .05;
        double digitWidth = (.9 * bigNumWidth / 2) * 0.95;
        double digitHeight = .9 * outerBoxHeight;
        double smallBoxWidth = outerBoxWidth * .25;
        double smallDigitWidth = (.9 * smallBoxWidth / 2) * 0.95;
        double smallDigitHeight = (outerBoxHeight / 2) * .9;

        Digit Digit1 = new Digit(outerBoxWidth * .02, outerBoxHeight * .05, digitWidth, digitHeight);
        Digit Digit2 = new Digit(outerBoxWidth * .04 + digitWidth, outerBoxHeight * .05, digitWidth, digitHeight);
        Digit Digit3 = new Digit(outerBoxWidth * .02 + bigNumWidth + colonWidth, outerBoxHeight * .05, digitWidth, digitHeight);
        Digit Digit4 = new Digit(outerBoxWidth * .04 + bigNumWidth + colonWidth + digitWidth, outerBoxHeight * .05, digitWidth, digitHeight);
        SmallDigit upperSmallDigit1 = new SmallDigit(bigNumWidth * 2 + colonWidth + smallBoxWidth * .04, outerBoxHeight * .03, smallDigitWidth, smallDigitHeight);
        SmallDigit upperSmallDigit2 = new SmallDigit(bigNumWidth * 2 + colonWidth + smallBoxWidth * .08 + smallDigitWidth, outerBoxHeight * .03, smallDigitWidth, smallDigitHeight);
        SmallDigit lowerSmallDigit1 = new SmallDigit(bigNumWidth * 2 + colonWidth + smallBoxWidth * .04, outerBoxHeight * .07 + smallDigitHeight, smallDigitWidth, smallDigitHeight);
        SmallDigit lowerSmallDigit2 = new SmallDigit(bigNumWidth * 2 + colonWidth + smallBoxWidth * .08 + smallDigitWidth, outerBoxHeight * .07 + smallDigitHeight, smallDigitWidth,
                smallDigitHeight);

        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.getChildren().add(outerBox);
        pane.getChildren().addAll(part1, part2, part3, part4);

        off(Digit1);
        off(Digit2);
        off(Digit3);
        off(Digit4);
        offSmall(lowerSmallDigit2);
        offSmall(lowerSmallDigit1);
        offSmall(upperSmallDigit2);
        offSmall(upperSmallDigit1);

        pane.getChildren().addAll(Digit1, Digit2, Digit3, Digit4, upperSmallDigit1, upperSmallDigit2, lowerSmallDigit1, lowerSmallDigit2);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, outerBoxWidth, outerBoxHeight);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("styleSheet.css").toExternalForm());

        primaryStage.setTitle("DIgital Analog Clock Beta 1");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        AnimationTimer animator = new AnimationTimer()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(long arg0)
            {
                // update
                Date date = new Date();
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.setTime(date);
                int minutes = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                int hours = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int seconds = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);

                int unitsMinutes = minutes % 10;
                int tensMinutes = minutes / 10;
                int unitsSeconds = seconds % 10;
                int tensSeconds = seconds / 10;
                int unitsHours = hours % 10;
                int tensHours = hours / 10;

                // render
                off(Digit1);
                off(Digit2);
                off(Digit3);
                off(Digit4);
                offSmall(lowerSmallDigit2);
                offSmall(lowerSmallDigit1);
                offSmall(upperSmallDigit2);
                offSmall(upperSmallDigit1);

                makeDigit(Digit1, tensHours);
                makeDigit(Digit2, unitsHours);
                makeDigit(Digit3, tensMinutes);
                makeDigit(Digit4, unitsMinutes);
                makeSmallDigit(upperSmallDigit1, tensSeconds);
                makeSmallDigit(upperSmallDigit2, unitsSeconds);
                //   makeSmallDigit();

            }
        };
        animator.start();
    }

    public void off(Digit digit)
    {
        digit.bottom.setId("off-digits");
        digit.middle.setId("off-digits");
        digit.top.setId("off-digits");
        digit.lowerLeft.setId("off-digits");
        digit.upperLeft.setId("off-digits");
        digit.lowerRight.setId("off-digits");
        digit.upperRight.setId("off-digits");
    }

    public void offSmall(SmallDigit digit)
    {
        digit.bottom.setId("off-digits");
        digit.middle.setId("off-digits");
        digit.top.setId("off-digits");
        digit.lowerLeft.setId("off-digits");
        digit.upperLeft.setId("off-digits");
        digit.lowerRight.setId("off-digits");
        digit.upperRight.setId("off-digits");
    }

    public void makeDigit(Digit digit, int n)
    {
        if (n == 0)
        {
            digit.top.setId("digits");
            digit.bottom.setId("digits");
            digit.lowerLeft.setId("digits");
            digit.upperLeft.setId("digits");
            digit.lowerRight.setId("digits");
            digit.upperRight.setId("digits");
        }
        else if (n == 1)
        {
            digit.upperRight.setId("digits");
            digit.lowerRight.setId("digits");
        }
        else if (n == 2)
        {
            digit.top.setId("digits");
            digit.upperRight.setId("digits");
            digit.middle.setId("digits");
            digit.lowerLeft.setId("digits");
            digit.bottom.setId("digits");
        }
        else if (n == 3)
        {
            digit.lowerRight.setId("digits");
            digit.upperRight.setId("digits");
            digit.top.setId("digits");
            digit.middle.setId("digits");
            digit.bottom.setId("digits");
        }
        else if (n == 4)
        {
            digit.middle.setId("digits");
            digit.lowerRight.setId("digits");
            digit.upperLeft.setId("digits");
            digit.upperRight.setId("digits");
        }
        else if (n == 5)
        {
            digit.top.setId("digits");
            digit.middle.setId("digits");
            digit.bottom.setId("digits");
            digit.upperLeft.setId("digits");
            digit.lowerRight.setId("digits");
        }
        else if (n == 6)
        {
            digit.top.setId("digits");
            digit.bottom.setId("digits");
            digit.middle.setId("digits");
            digit.lowerLeft.setId("digits");
            digit.upperLeft.setId("digits");
            digit.lowerRight.setId("digits");
            //digit.upperRight.setId("digits");
        }
        else if (n == 7)
        {
            digit.top.setId("digits");
            //digit.bottom.setId("digits");
            //digit.middle.setId("digits");
            //digit.lowerLeft.setId("digits");
            //digit.upperLeft.setId("digits");
            digit.lowerRight.setId("digits");
            digit.upperRight.setId("digits");
        }
        else if (n == 8)
        {
            digit.top.setId("digits");
            digit.bottom.setId("digits");
            digit.middle.setId("digits");
            digit.lowerLeft.setId("digits");
            digit.upperLeft.setId("digits");
            digit.lowerRight.setId("digits");
            digit.upperRight.setId("digits");
        }
        else if (n == 9)
        {
            digit.top.setId("digits");
            digit.bottom.setId("digits");
            digit.middle.setId("digits");
            digit.upperLeft.setId("digits");
            digit.lowerRight.setId("digits");
            digit.upperRight.setId("digits");
        }
    }

    public void makeSmallDigit(SmallDigit digit, int n)
    {
        if (n == 0)
        {
            digit.top.setId("digits");
            digit.bottom.setId("digits");
            digit.lowerLeft.setId("digits");
            digit.upperLeft.setId("digits");
            digit.lowerRight.setId("digits");
            digit.upperRight.setId("digits");
        }
        else if (n == 1)
        {
            digit.upperRight.setId("digits");
            digit.lowerRight.setId("digits");
        }
        else if (n == 2)
        {
            digit.top.setId("digits");
            digit.upperRight.setId("digits");
            digit.middle.setId("digits");
            digit.lowerLeft.setId("digits");
            digit.bottom.setId("digits");
        }
        else if (n == 3)
        {
            digit.lowerRight.setId("digits");
            digit.upperRight.setId("digits");
            digit.top.setId("digits");
            digit.middle.setId("digits");
            digit.bottom.setId("digits");
        }
        else if (n == 4)
        {
            digit.middle.setId("digits");
            digit.lowerRight.setId("digits");
            digit.upperLeft.setId("digits");
            digit.upperRight.setId("digits");
        }
        else if (n == 5)
        {
            digit.top.setId("digits");
            digit.middle.setId("digits");
            digit.bottom.setId("digits");
            digit.upperLeft.setId("digits");
            digit.lowerRight.setId("digits");
        }
        else if (n == 6)
        {
            digit.top.setId("digits");
            digit.bottom.setId("digits");
            digit.middle.setId("digits");
            digit.lowerLeft.setId("digits");
            digit.upperLeft.setId("digits");
            digit.lowerRight.setId("digits");
        }
        else if (n == 7)
        {
            digit.top.setId("digits");
            digit.lowerRight.setId("digits");
            digit.upperRight.setId("digits");
        }
        else if (n == 8)
        {
            digit.top.setId("digits");
            digit.bottom.setId("digits");
            digit.middle.setId("digits");
            digit.lowerLeft.setId("digits");
            digit.upperLeft.setId("digits");
            digit.lowerRight.setId("digits");
            digit.upperRight.setId("digits");
        }
        else if (n == 9)
        {
            digit.top.setId("digits");
            digit.bottom.setId("digits");
            digit.middle.setId("digits");
            digit.upperLeft.setId("digits");
            digit.lowerRight.setId("digits");
            digit.upperRight.setId("digits");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: @James_D just tagging you. think you might be knowing this